# C++ string variables not accepting enter and tab whitespace?

Tags: c++

Why does the following work:

```
string input = "a long string of text pasted from a .txt file";
```

But this version does not?

```
    string input =
    
                "
    
                some
    
                    large
    
                        string ";
```

I thought C++ doesn't care about whitespace.

Comment: What does 'doesn't work' mean?

Comment: First of all please [edit] your question to include a proper [mcve]. Then please tell us the actual and expected output (or result) of the shown program.

Comment: I get a compile error.

Comment: @Mr.Green Compile errors can range from `expected unqualified-id` to unresolved overloads, the specific error helps more than stating that it doesn't compile

Comment: If you get a compile error you need to add the text of the error message to your question and I mean text no pictures of text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like this. It's called a [raw string literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal):

```cpp
string input =
            R"(
            some
                large
                    string )";
```

This will include the endline characters as well. The format is `R"(string-literal)"`

Answer (score 4):

For the most parts no, it does not care about whitespace. But there are exceptions and string literals are one of them.

The rule is string literals cannot span multiple lines. But adjacent literals are automatically concatenated so you can just do

```
const char string[] = "very "
                      "long "
                      "string";
```

and it will be equivalent to

```
const char string[] = "very long string";
```

I am not sure about the origin of the rule, I suspect it might have been done to prevent confusion whether the newline should be part of the string or not (it's not unless explicitly escaped). Or maybe just some grammar/parser thing. Compiling C/C++ is kind of complicated and happens in multiple phases, see [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/translation_phases) - string literals already have plenty of special treatment.